How can you use the selected value of a field parameter to select a value of another field parameter in Power BI?
In Power BI, can the selection of a value of a field parameter be used as input to select the value of another field parameter? To be more specific: I have a matrix whose rows are either "filing year" or "new business effective year". The type of year is selected using a field parameter. The columns are either the quarter of the filing year or the quarter of the new business effective year, depending on the type of year selected. I would like the "year type" field parameter to automatically control a "quarter type" field parameter to get the right rows and columns in the matrix. That is, I'd like to be able to toggle between the two matrices below, using just one filter.

